# How do I capture PrtScr to define it as HotKey?

Tags: keyboard, settings, screenshot

I want to define Shutter as my screenshot tool with <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>. When I follow [these instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/printscreen-launch-shutter-area-selection-ubuntu-18-04/), I need to select the hotkey. But when I press <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to do that, <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> does its thing and takes a screenshot with the default tool! How do I get the settings screen to capture my choice of <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> as the HotKey?

Comment: i tried it and working fine. i have disabled gnome-screenshot short cut first. and then given `shutter -f` as command for shortcut `print` are you not expecting same way or different?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGfyE.gif

Comment: Strangely, when I hit CTRL-PRTSCR at that stage, a screenshot is taken (rather than capturing this as a key to put in the settings).

Comment: But I worked around this and now SHIFT-PRTSCR does I what I want, though not with Shutter.

Comment: Normally, when you press prtn screen in Ubuntu, it shows you a window to select what you want to do with the screenshot (copy to clipboard, save, ...) Maybe you are using a laptop with multimedia buttons that use prnt screen as multimedia key?
you tried a combo with FN button?